# sqlstateserver appid vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, session

Im trying to figure out how to get and separate the appid and the sessionid that gets returned by sqlserver for stateserver. I need to get this info in my webapp and i do not have access to the sqlserver other than to read the information.

in the docs:Curiously, the ASPStateTempSessions table lacks an AppId column linking it to ASPTempStateApplications. The linkage occurs in ASPStateTempSessions's SessionId field, which doesn't store just session IDs. It stores session IDs with application IDs appended to them. The statement

```
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = id + _partitionInfo.AppSuffix
```

so i have this value in the AspStateTempApplications table:

```
    appid            appname
    -796116323     /w3svc/*/root/fsco*tbsc
```

i have identified in the session table my session info with the appid converted?

```
sessionid
cp5p2trw5navwnsgmhdzctnn2341447f
```

the portion at the back: 2341447f should correspond to -796116323 but if i run a hexadecimal convert function it either barfs on the negative sign or using online converters gives me the wrong value. how can i get that value, i would like to query session values

what am i missing here.. it seems straightforward

Comment: i guess its actually the appname and not the appid that is converted to a value. still dont know how its getting converted

Comment: check out this question - it could help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604603/ms-sql-server-convert-hex-string-to-integer

Comment: did you tried with ***CONVERT*** function ? `select convert(int, convert(varbinary, '0x9fa38ee5', 1))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SUBSTRING(a.SessionId, 25, 8) AS AppIDHex,
```

and convert AppId to HEX

```
SUBSTRING(sys.fn_varbintohexstr(CONVERT(VarBinary,b.AppId)), 3, 8)
```

**SQL code:**

```
  SELECT 
    a.SessionId, 
    SUBSTRING(a.SessionId, 25, 8) AS AppIDHex, 
    b.AppId AS AppIDDec, 
    b.AppName, 
    DATALENGTH(a.SessionItemLong) AS SessionSize 
FROM 
    dbo.ASPStateTempSessions AS a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.ASPStateTempApplications AS b 
    ON 
    SUBSTRING(a.SessionId, 25, 8) = 
    SUBSTRING(sys.fn_varbintohexstr(CONVERT(VarBinary,b.AppId)), 3, 8)
```

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rextang/2008/01/12/asp-net-checking-session-size-in-sql-server-aspstate-db/