# Convert string into bit(32) alternative in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, bit, data-conversion, bigint

SQL Server does not offer a `bit(32)` data type (such as Postgres). I need to convert a `string` into a `bit(32)` and then into `bigint` and later on into a `timestamp`.

I can give an example:

I have to convert this string "x5c081ca4" into a bit(32) value: "01011100000010000001110010100100", then to bigint: 1544035492 and then to timestamp: "2018-12-05 19:44:52+01"

In Postgres these would be the functions:
TO_TIMESTAMP(timeconv::bit(32)::BIGINT)

Any ideas how I can solve the problem?

Comment: You haven't described any problem yet. Convert what string into what? What does `such as Postgres` mean? With so little information, the only answer is `Yes to all`

Comment: Showing your intended input and output would help.

Comment: BTW why go through a `bit(32)` if the real target is an `int`? Is the real question how to parse a 32-bit hex string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS SQL server - convert HEX string to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604603/ms-sql-server-convert-hex-string-to-integer)

Comment: No need to go through a bit string at all. `SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(BINARY(4), '0x5c081ca4', 1)), '19700101')`. Ironically, the harder part of this problem is converting the timestamp into local time, if that's what you need -- T-SQL can switch around time zones now but still has no simple function for the current local time zone name. You can convert the result to a `DATETIMEOFFSET` if you're OK with just the UTC time.

Comment: How would that conversion look like?  `TODATETIMEOFFSET(DATEADD(SECOND, CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(BINARY(4), '0x5c081ca4', 1)), '19700101')), CURRENT_TIMEZONE())` But that doesn't work.

Comment: Instead of `CURRENT_TIMEZONE()` I also tried `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`, without success.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server *has* a [`binary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) data type:

```
select cast(cast('abcd' as binary(4)) as int)
```

The length is in bytes and not bits, but it probably does what you want.

Note:  `int`s are four bytes, so you don't need a `bigint`.

Comment: Instead of 1544035492, this leads to a value of 2016764720. So no, this does not work.