# Extract Hex String from varbinary to File

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes, type-conversion

this is pretty much a noob question but i can't find a solution.

I'm using a SQL Server Database. In one table a column has the DataType varbinary(max). The values for this column are shown a hex values(When i'm using a select - query).  What is the best way to write the shown hex String completly into a text file?

Two Constraints:
* Copy&Paste is not an Option. The value i want to extract has a length of approx. 69000 Chars. The Windows Clipboard seems to store only around 43000 Chars.
* I've tried to save the query Result as a .csv File. But the maximum size for these files is around 65000 chars.

Comment: Why can't you query that column, store it in a StringBuffer and then write it to a File?

Comment: Would this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5172100/2061621

Comment: Using transact SQL? Or Java? I've been using a small Java Program to query the value. But i don't know which method to call to get the hex value and not the bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line:

> ```
> bcp "select * from [<yourtable>]" queryout C:\Temp\yourfile.dat -S yourserver -d yourDatabase -T -c
> ```

-T means a Trusted Connection; you can use -U and -P to supply a user name as password.

Comment: Whooohoooo!!! :-) Works! Thanks. I've tried bcp yesterday but did not give the Database as an extra Parameter. I've had it in my query.