# How to convert Binary data to text data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to convert binary data  to text?

I have column called File names  in test table with image datatype so when i am selecting the data from test table its showing the data for file names column is binary data i.e ('0x433A5C55736535').

Regards
Anji

Comment: Can you change the column type to something more appropriate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert integer to hex and hex to integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703019/convert-integer-to-hex-and-hex-to-integer)

Comment: Agree with @CDahn `image` datatype is a crazy choice for storing file names. It is for large binary data and deprecated. Not for fairly short text strings.

Answer (score 5):

I can't beleive nobody answered this. If it's image data you won't get anything readable. but in case it is text data in a binary field, you can do this:

```
select cast(DataColumn as varchar(MAX)) as DataAsText from [TableWithData];
```

Comment: I also sometimes get amazed at how SO community behaves. Can somebody explain why a simple, clear, and specific question like this wasn't answered for 7 years?

Answer (score -2):

'0x433A5C55736535' is not binary data, binary data is composed only with 0 and 1.

I think you need to use the defined functions of your test table to get the data you want, if you are in MySQL it's "Select * from file names"

Comment: It's the hex representation of binary data.