# Conversion Failed Nvarchar to INT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-convert

I have two tables called **Entry_Data** and **Data**

**Entry_Data** has three columns:

EntryID DataID  DataTypeID

1         50        18

2         49        59

30       28      16

Data has two columns:

**DataID**  **Value**

50         0x00000000033654

49           Removable

28           E:\Test.txt

The Value column is an nvarchar field.

I have written a left join while attempting to convert all Value fields that start with 0x to an int so that the Hexadecimal value can be converted into a meaningful and human readable value however I get the error:

> **Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value
>   ‘0x00000000033654’ to data type int**

```
SELECT TOP 100
  Entry_Data.DataTypeID AS DataTypeID,
  CAST(Data.Value AS nvarchar(440)) AS Value,
  Data.DataID AS DataID
FROM ActivityLog.Entry_Data
LEFT JOIN ActivityLog.Data
  ON ActivityLog.Entry_Data.DataID =
                                    CASE
                                      WHEN DataTypeID = 18 AND
                                        Value LIKE '%0x%' THEN CONVERT(nvarchar, CONVERT(int, Value, 1))
                                      ELSE DataTypeID
                                    END
WHERE DataTypeID = 18
```

Comment: You getting the error because you are comparing an int value with nvarchar in `JOIN` condition.

Comment: Could you propose how it should look please?

Comment: You are trying to check `DataID` with `Value` i.e 50 to `0x00000000033654` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Unfortunately that is how the tables are set out so i cannot to a join on anything else. Are you saying that what i am attempting to achieve is impossible?

Comment: Maybe, you can see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703019/convert-integer-to-hex-and-hex-to-integer

Answer (score 0):

In your `case expression`, you are returning an `nvarchar` for one situation

```
 THEN CONVERT(nvarchar, CONVERT(int, Value, 1))
```

and an integer for the second situation

```
ELSE DataTypeID
```

You need to correct your join so it always return and int for the join to work.

Comment: The Value field will not always be an INT so would ELSE Value work? Thanks for the reply

Comment: I think you have possible misused the join statement here.  the join would always be on the Data_ID columns, your case expression for making the results readable should be part of the select statement.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you give me an example please? I am not a native SQL writer

Comment: Unless I have misread your question, something like this might be what you want:  
    `SELECT TOP 100 
 Entry_Data.DataTypeID AS DataTypeID, 
 CAST(Data.Value AS nvarchar(440)) AS Value,
 CASE WHEN DataTypeID = 18 AND Value LIKE '%0x%' 
 THEN CONVERT(nvarchar, CONVERT(int, Value, 1))
        ELSE DataTypeID END as FormattedValue,
 Data.DataID AS DataID
FROM Entry_Data
LEFT JOIN Data
  ON Entry_Data.DataID = Data.DataID`

Comment: Hi, The Formatted Value = DataTypeID when i search 1000 rows but DataTypeID does not equal 18 in any of them. I added a WHERE clause to equal DataTypeID and i got Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ‘0x00000000033654’ to data type int.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't update the case statement before I put the comment in.  Something like this should work, the conversion is working here  SELECT TOP 100 
Entry_Data.DataTypeID AS DataTypeID, 
CAST(Data.Value AS nvarchar(440)) AS Value, 

CASE WHEN DataTypeID = 18 AND Value LIKE '%0x%' THEN SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar,CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary, Data.Value, 1))) ELSE Data.Value END as FormattedValue, 

Data.DataID AS DataID 

FROM Entry_Data LEFT JOIN Data ON Entry_Data.DataID = Data.DataID