# Convert integer to hexa in sql

Tags: sql-server

I want to convert `int` to `hexadecimal` in SQL.

Example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), 162)
```

> Result :0x000000A2

Actual value is this

> A2

Why I am getting unnecessary part at prefix?

Can I remove previous part?

What is right way to handle it?

Comment: What unnecessary part? That value looks correct for a `varbinary` to me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert integer to hex and hex to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703019/convert-integer-to-hex-and-hex-to-integer)

Answer (score 2):

To quote the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#converting-binary-and-varbinary-data):

> When other data types are converted to binary or varbinary, the data is padded or truncated on the left. Padding is achieved by using hexadecimal zeros.

You're specifying `VARBINARY(8)` in your query, so the result is padded with zeros to that length. If you need the value without the padding for some reason, specify `VARBINARY(1)`, which will return `0xA2`.

*Note: They're both the same value*

**Alternatively**, if you just want a 2 character string:

`SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CONVERT(VARBINARY(8),162),2), 2)`

Which will return `A2`

Comment: It work for me.PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CONVERT(VARBINARY(1), 162),2)

Comment: @Pinky, okay, as long as you know the length of the significant figures

Answer (score 0):

At a complete a total guess in the absence of any response from the OP:

```
SELECT V.BloatedHex,
       ISNULL(STUFF(V.BloatedHex,1,NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^0]%',V.BloatedHex),0)-1,''),0)
FROM (VALUES(STUFF(CONVERT(varchar(10),CONVERT(varbinary(8),162),1),1,2,''))) V(BloatedHex);
```

This returns the **`varchar(10)`** value `'A2'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one statement like this,

```
DECLARE @someNumber BIGINT = 162;

WITH Hex AS (
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(34), CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), @someNumber), 2) [Value]
)
SELECT SUBSTRING([Value], PATINDEX('%[^0]%', [Value]), 34) FROM Hex
```

;

This does not use any unsupported internal functions and attempts to minimize string manipulation.

Better still, don't write this kind of presentation code with TSQL, it is not what it is good at. Worry about making it look pretty when you display the value to the user.